# Python: returning an instance of derived class from a base class method

Tags: python

Assume the following situation. There is a base class holding some data and a derived class which assumes that the data now has some additional characteristic which allows for running `algorithm`. The base class also has an algorithm that processes the data in some generic way and returns a copy which is the result of processing. Now, that processing does not affect the specific characteristic of the data and therefore we can safely assume that the returned value should be of the type of the derived class.

My current implementation:

```
class GenericData:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self._d = d

    def process(self):
        # Process the data in a way that is compatible
        # with any specialization. Then, return an instance
        # of the specific derived class.
        return type(self)(some_processing(self._d))


class SpecificData(GenericData):

    """This class is just a gathering of algorithms that make
       certain assumptions about d."""

    def __init__(self, d):
        super().__init__(d)

    def algorithm():
        # Do some stuff assuming certain characteristic of data
        pass
```

My question is: Is this a good/Pythonic way of handling such a case? The answer to that question could be either a different design pattern or a better implementation of the pattern used above.

Comment: I don't understand. Does `algorithm()` call into `process()`?

Comment: I guess the answer is really dependent on the broader context. It's easy to get lost in inheritance and fancy ways of deriving classes. Here, for example, you could argue that each derived class should simply implement its own `process`, calling `super().process()` and returning the appropriate (but more rigidly fixed) class. But if you have dozens of derived classes, that feels like a lot code duplication (then again, do you need so many derived classes?)

Comment: @BrianNeal No, here it only serves as a justification for having the derived class. It basically is a group of algorithms making certain assumption about d.

Comment: @Evert, true, the thing is that process() is a long piece of code that is identical for all data, independently of the specification.

Comment: @And But that is negated by calling `super().process()`, right? I'm not saying I'm correct, but sometimes doing it this way can make things a lot clearer (e.g., years later, one doesn't have to look up the inheritance chain to find out where process is actually called: it's clear very quickly from the super() call).

Comment: @Evert, that is also correct. It's just that one has to define such a wrapper class for every derived class. And it's only role is to "cast" the output of processing. Would be nice to get rid of that.

Comment: Sure, and I think for now that what you have will work fine. Just to belabor my previous point a bit more: your tracebacks if some_processing fails, may also be more confusing though. It is really a tradeoff between convenience and potential obscurity later on.

Comment: I think you may be going down the wrong path, but not sure where to point you. One small suggestion is use `self.__class__` instead of `type(self)` although it doesn't solve the greater question.

Comment: One example that I know and where I think you can have a look how this is done by other people. is the Django framework (but the amount of digging into the code may put you off). And, as a matter of fact, their class-based views are confusing to understand if you want to do a bit more than the default (these class-based views are definite examples of long inheritances chains with mixins and all kind of magic happening way up the chain; one issue is that you can lose track of the order of method calls).

Comment: Btw, I don't understand your second question ("Also, what if ..."); because it will work as you have specified it there. Then again, that should probably be a separate question (since I don't see how it ties in the process() part).

Comment: @Evert, true, scratch that second part.

Comment: @mehtunguh That's a bit my feeling as well, though it'll depend on context. Can you explain why `self.__class__`, and not `type(self)`, btw? I don't disagree, I'm just curious what `type(self)` can return that would cause things to fail, for example.

Comment: @mehtunguh I'm on python 3 and don't require backward compatibility, so it's basically the same thing then.

Comment: @Evert actually it won't matter if you're in python3. `type` might even be better since it's builtin instead of magic. But for older versions of python, `type` may return something stupid like `<type 'instance'>`

Comment: Thanks for some pros/cons discussion. I was basically just curious if there is a better design pattern that I'm obviously missing here.

Comment: @And the main weirdness here is having an instance method return a new instance of it's class. can you explain why not just assign the result of `some_processing(self._d)` to another attribute and access it that way? For example, `self._d = some_processing(self._d)` or `self._pd = some_processing(self._d)`

Comment: @mehtunguh, basically to make it independent from the original data. Let's say that `d` is a large array that stores some signal. Now `process` can for instance be doing downsampling. Then, I would like to have the downsampled signal in its own instance.

Comment: @mehtunguh, I guess an alternative would be to do a deep copy of the instance and then internally modify the _d. However, if `processing` needs to copy data anyways, that seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: @And yeah in that case there is not a better way. There are more robust ways using metaclasses, but I think that would be a waste of your time for this.

Comment: Making a base class aware of derived classes is poor object-oriented design.